# Botao Like customizado

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

Alguém sabe se é possível customizar o `like button` do `facebook SDK`? Preciso usar minha imagem como fundo do botão ou fazer dela um botão.

```
    var likeControl:FBSDKLikeControl = FBSDKLikeControl()
    likeControl.objectID = fbPage
    likeControl.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyle.BoxCount
    likeControl.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "fblike")!)
    likeControl.frame = CGRectMake(16,20, 290, 40)
    self.viewBotoes.addSubview(likeControl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se essa é a melhor maneira, porém funcionou legal aqui:

[image: resultado]

---

Você vai precisar alterar a classe do framework do facebook diretamente, como aqui eu instalei o SDK via `cocoapods` eu consigo acessar as pastas contendo as classes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Então só precisa abrir a classe `FBSDKButton` que está dentro de `Pods > FBSDKCoreKit > arc` procure pelo método que começa com `_configureWithIcon:(FBSDKIcon *)icon` e adicione o seguinte código no mesmo lugar que está abaixo:

```
...
  BOOL forceSizeToFit = CGRectIsEmpty(self.bounds);

  CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
  UIImage *backgroundImage;

  // Crie um novo UIImage com a sua imagem
  UIImage *custom = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backCustomLike"];

  backgroundImage = [self _backgroundImageWithColor:backgroundColor cornerRadius:3.0 scale:scale];

  // Coloque a sua nova imagem aqui
  [self setBackgroundImage:custom forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  backgroundImage = [self _backgroundImageWithColor:highlightedColor cornerRadius:3.0 scale:scale];
  [self setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

  backgroundImage = [self _backgroundImageWithColor:[self defaultDisabledColor] cornerRadius:3.0 scale:scale];
  [self setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
...
```